# Can you craft watches in Terraria mobile?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I can't seem to craft watches. Does anyone know how to?
Or, alternatively, where I can find them?

Answer (score 4):

[Watches on the Terraria wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Watches)

As noted on this page, watches are only available in desktop and console versions of Terraria. In addition, the update history lists the fact that watches in the mobile version cannot be crafted.

Since the only legitimate way to obtain watches is via crafting, you cannot currently obtain watches in the mobile version of Terraria.

Answer (score 1):

Watches are not craftable on Terraria Mobile.